# How to check the text of a tkinter Button?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I'm trying to make a simple GUI in which when a button is clicked in the window, the code runs a conditional check on the text of the button and then prints "This is a test" in the command line. The problem is that whenever I click the button, the text won't display. How do I fix this?

I don't really have any other ideas on what to try except what I'm doing right now.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def buttonchange(button):
    if button["text"] == " ":
      button["text"] = "X"
button = StringVar()
btn1 = Button(text=" ", command=lambda:buttonchange(btn1))
btn1.pack()
btn2 = Button(text=" ", command=lambda:buttonchange(btn2))
btn2.pack()
if btn2["text"] == "X":
    print("This is a test.")
root.mainloop()
```

Whenever I click the button, nothing shows in the command line? I want to show "This is a test" with an `if`/`else` statement.

Comment: Tkinter is "user-event-driven", which means that everything has to happen within the `mainloop()`— such as shown in @Heyran.rs's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54728493/355230).

Comment: Thank you so much, had it not been for you I would've been looking around for hours, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Set print() in `buttonchange`:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def buttonchange(button):
    if button["text"] == " ":
      button["text"] = "X"
      print("This is a test.")

button = StringVar()
btn1 = Button(text=" ", command=lambda:buttonchange(btn1))
btn1.pack()
btn2 = Button(text=" ", command=lambda:buttonchange(btn2))
btn2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```